# Onclick body scroll down 100vh only at the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this JS that works just on the first click, no idea why.
I would love it to work continuously every scroll down.

```
$('body').click(function(){
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 300);
return false;
});
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/e1w4hrgh/

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the current scroll position

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: window.pageYOffset + $(window).height()}, 300);
```

In your code you always scroll to the height of the window which is alwas for example 600px if you click again you scroll form 600 to 600. Therefore just add the currentposition + window height and there you go.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1w4hrgh/1/

Comment: Any idea why it's working on Safari but not working on Chrome?

Comment: Tested in in chrome therefore it shuld actually work